# Docker-compose and connection problem between services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, database-connection, postgis

First of all, i know this is a terrible docker-compose file, but is small version of something that I want to ask.

I have a service (api) that needs to connect with a different database, I MUST run this database on different ports (not 5432)

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: bash -c "sleep 10;apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet && telnet data_second 5433"
    depends_on:
      - data
      - data_second
  data:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  data_second:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: somedb
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
```

This is the output

```
(Reading database ... 4127 files and directories currently installed.)
api_1          | Preparing to unpack .../archives/netbase_6.1_all.deb ...
api_1          | Unpacking netbase (6.1) ...
api_1          | Selecting previously unselected package telnet.
api_1          | Preparing to unpack .../telnet_0.17-41.2build1_amd64.deb ...
api_1          | Unpacking telnet (0.17-41.2build1) ...
api_1          | Setting up netbase (6.1) ...
api_1          | Setting up telnet (0.17-41.2build1) ...
api_1          | update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/telnet.netkit to provide /usr/bin/telnet (telnet) in auto mode
api_1          | update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/telnet.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/telnet.netkit.1.gz (of link group telnet) doesn't exist
api_1          | Trying 192.168.144.3...
api_1          | telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
a_host_api_1 exited with code 1
```

Any idea why i cannot connect to that port? (i can connect to the other database in port 5432, but not with the database that is on 5433)

It's running on a mac Monterey, with the last version of docker.

Thanks in advance!!!! I'm sure that has to be something that im missing and cannot see it now.

Comment: If you’re using docker network (as it seems to be) you don’t need port remap, just expose postgres on a different port (5433)

Comment: but what if i cannot change the port on of a service, there is no way to do it?

Comment: You cannot connect because you are running `telnet` inside a container that shares the same network with the db container, and not the one of the host network. How you map ports here does not really matter because the port is always going to be 5432 (You are interested in the right part of the mapping). Try `telnet data_second 5432` and it should work.

Comment: it's crazy that i don't find the way to change the port on any postgis implementation.

Comment: @Horacio on the first question: you don't need to mind about ports while you're in a docker network, because it's addressed by container name as @marco.luzzara pointed out. However you could try to mount an updated `postgresql.conf`file remapping the port and overwrite with a bind mount the one inside the container, but you may encounter unexpected side effects